# ACM bibtex format missing title

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, acm

I am using ACM format (Strict Adherence to SIGS style) to edit my bibtex file. The problem is that the compiler gave me the following error and corresponds to the following code:

```
 @INCOLLECTION{Platt99a,
 AUTHOR = "Platt, John C.",
 CHAPTER = "Fast training of support vector machines using sequential minimal optimization",
 BOOKTITLE = {Advances in kernel methods},
 PUBLISHER = "MIT Press",
 ADDRESS = "Cambridge, MA, USA",
 YEAR = {1999}  } 

 Warning--empty title in Platt99a
```

I can't find any problem with my code. How to fix it?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `incollection` type requires the `author`, `title`, `booktitle`, `publisher`, and `year` fields. Your entry has no `title` field, hence the warning. On the other hand, the `chapter` field should contain a number. So move the content of `chapter` to `title`, and maybe find out which chapter number it is to fill the `chapter` field.

Comment: I changed the 'chapter' to 'title' and it works, actually, 'chapter' is 'title' in my case. thx